# swipe gesture that reply action

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I have this code:

```js
var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});
controller.on('gesture', function (gesture){
    console.log(gesture);
    if(gesture.type === 'swipe'){
        handleSwipe(gesture);
    }
});
function handleSwipe (swipe){
    var startFrameID;
    if(swipe.state === 'stop'){
        if (swipe.direction[0] > 0){
            //this means that the swipe is to the right direction
   slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
   slidePict("sx");
   },500);
        }else{
            //this means that the swipe is to the left direction
   slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
   slidePict("dx");
   },500);
        }
    }
}
controller.connect();
```

It works fine, due recognize swipe gesture, but when the gesture is performed, both to the left and towards the right, the slide seems to receive two successive input, and then taking two / three slide following...
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe gestures are generated by the finger tips -- not the hand-- so you could get up to 5 swipe events per hand per frame. Then, the next frame, you will get swipe events updating the properties of each gesture.

You could modify your code as follows, so that it waits for the current swipe action to finish before allowing another action to start:

```
var isSwiping = false;
var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});
controller.on('gesture', function (gesture){
    console.log(gesture);
    if(gesture.type === 'swipe' && !isSwiping){
        isSwiping = true;
        handleSwipe(gesture);
    }
});
function handleSwipe (swipe){
    var startFrameID;
        if (swipe.direction[0] > 0){
            //this means that the swipe is to the right direction
            slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            slidePict("sx");
            isSwiping = false;
            },500);
        }else{
            //this means that the swipe is to the left direction
            slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            slidePict("dx");
            isSwiping = false;
            },500);
        }
}
controller.connect();
```

[edit] removed `if(swipe.state == "stop"){}` clause from `handleSwipe()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, anyway it don't solve my trouble.
Even with this code, the problem remain the same: the slide function is call many times on each swipe gesture...
:-(

Comment: That's odd. It worked fine for me. I did have to remove the if(swipe.state == stop) clause -- but that had caused the opposite problem -- I generally didn't get any swipes. Once I removed that clause, I could get at most 2 triggers with one swipe and only if I moved my hand very slowly. I tried it on 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

Comment: Anyway, I solve the question.
I create a variable 'slideOnOff and set it as "on".
When the slide function is called, the variable is set to "off", and when the function is executed, with a setTimeout I reset it to "on" after 1'.
Then, I do the check below:
   `if(slideOnOff == 'on'){
        if (swipe.direction[0] > 0){
            slidePict("dx");
        } else {
            slidePict("sx");
        }
    }`